# jinja2 in python does not print data to template

Tags: python, jinja2

Hello I just started using Jinja2 templates in python to build a website but the problem that I face is while printing the template in python console does not print the data to it. And at some point it gives me

```
<built-in method title of str object at 0x7f9adefebe70>
```

Here is my delete.html file

```
{% for Data in results %}
  <h3>{{ Data.u_id }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.p_id }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.name }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.email }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.title }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.body }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.upvotes }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.comments }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ Data.date_created }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Below is the results that is dict obtained from database

```
{'body': 'they are hostel', 'name': 'suraj', 'title': 'betas',
 'p_id': 1L, 'comments': 2L, 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 25, 10, 36, 28),
 'upvotes': 0L, 'u_id': 1L, 'email': 'suraj@exmaple.com'}
```

The following code i run in python shell

```
import jinja2
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('./delete.html')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template('')
print template.render(results=results)
```

But I get the following output (following is repeated in the output statement)

```
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3><built-in method title of str object at 0x7f9adc8012a0></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
```

What my output should be is that in `delete.html` it should print the respective data from the dict that I send.

How to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is a single dict, not a list of dicts. So when you iterate through it, you get the keys, which are strings. You should remove the for loop and just refer to `{{ results.title }}` etc.

Comment: I got to know my mistake  ..thanks to your help!! .. and also the above code works when we put the nested dict .. thanks again!!